# Assembly: TASM illegal command

Tags: wine, programming, dosbox

Few weeks ago I asked for a similar TASM compiler, but seems that the instructor wants nothing but TASM. So I installed [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tasmforwindows/) using wine in DosBox.

But no matter what my code is, when I run `tasm helllo.asm` I get

`illegal command: TASM`

I tried different tasm packages, including the official tasm 5.

Would you please try to run the software I linked to above in Dosbox? and see if you can actually execute anything? I'm on a 64 bit intel pc.

Comment: Any chance you can share a asm file to test? Without a file to do an exact test it does seem to be working for me.. How are you launching it? (btw, I'm pretty sure SO wouldn't like this kind of question..)

Comment: @Seth here's an example http://wenkaru.blogspot.com/2013/01/assembly-language-hello-world-program.html and here's my code http://pastebin.com/SGaEzmtL well if it fits and can be answered here no need for SO :)

Comment: Great thanks. One last question, how are you running launching tasm? and do you have dosbox installed *in* wine? (I guess that's two :P)

Comment: Appears to work for me: http://i.imgur.com/oJ1poUf.jpg You'll need to give more information about your setup so we can figure out what went wrong, or I can just add an answer detailing what I did to get it to work.

Comment: @Seth wait a second I want to try what you just did, I want to put it on the desktop and refer to it as `:D` how u knew that? yes dosbox and wine are installed and installed it using wine and it opened in dosbox, i tried `tasm test.asm`  i put the asm file in the same in the ASSEMBLY directory, it was created by wine when I installed the package

Comment: @Seth are you using the same software I linked to in my question or did you download the official tasm? yes please add an answer and i'll follow your steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell why it doesn't work for you without more information about your setup, but this is how I set it up and it works just fine (as far as I can tell, not knowing assembly).

[Download Tasm for Windows from sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tasmforwindows/files/?source=navbar) and install it with WINE.  Then download and install [dosbox for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dosbox/files/dosbox/0.74/DOSBox0.74-win32-installer.exe/download) (direct link).

Now you should have two shortcuts on your desktop:

- Tasm 1.4  Windows 7 - Windows 8 64bit By Techapple.net
- DOSBox 0.74

Double click the Tasm shortcut. You should be presented with a maximized DOSBox window. If you don't want to work in maximized mode press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Now we appear a bit stuck, since `C:\` is mounted as a WINE virtual disk at the location of Tasm. The simplest way around this is simply mount a new drive letter at the folder where your `.asm` files are located.

```
mount d /path/to/asm/files
```

In my case I had a file `test.asm` on the desktop. Now run your file(s) with the command:

```
tasm D:\name\or\path\to-file
```

[image]

and you're done!

Comment: worked! do i have to keep referring to it as `tasm D:/test.asm`? cant I just write `tasm test.asm`?

Comment: @Fischer No, the `D:` is necessary because without it DOS will look for `test.asm` in the current directory, which just contains the Tasm files. Run `dir` to see what I mean.

Comment: do you know the answer to this one? :D http://askubuntu.com/questions/552968/how-to-automount-multiple-drives-in-dosbox

Answer (score 0):

Things you can check is

> Make Sure Tasm.exe present inside Bin

In my case I was working on windows 10 ,tasm keyword was working fine then it threw the same error ,then i checked inside bin folder and **tasm.exe** was not there but only **tasm32.exe** then i just used,that tasm.exe file may be deleted.

```
tasm32 yourprogramname.asm
```